# Little oh notation in the exponent

Tags: analytic-number-theory

So I saw this notation in my analytic number theory course: $|f(n)|\leq n^{o(1)}$. So I am wondering whether this is the same as the notation $|f(n)|\leq o(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

$o(1)$ represents an unknown function that is tending to $0$ as $n\to\infty$; so, for every $\varepsilon>0$, we have $|o(1)|<\varepsilon$ when $n$ is large enough in terms of $\varepsilon$. Therefore $|f(n)| \le n^\varepsilon$ when $n$ is large enough in terms of $\varepsilon$, which is actually much stronger than $f(n) = o(n)$.

One example of a function satisfying $|f(n)| \le n^{o(1)}$ is $f(n) = \log n$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{o(1)} $ can be any value between $0$ and $\infty$.  So it is not bounded below by $|\log(n)|$.  For example, $-1/\log(n)=o(1)$ as $n\to \infty$.  And $n^{-1/\log(n)}=1/e$

Comment: hence "one example"

Comment: Greg, it's not an example unless more is known about the nature of the function that is $o(1)$.  That is, $|f(n)|=|\log(n)|$ is not a lower bound of $n^{o(1)}$ unless we know more about the function that is little O of $1$.

Comment: However, given that the only information we have about $f(n)$ is $|f(n)| \le n^{o(1)}$, any function satisfying that bound is indeed an example. Additional context might change that, but we have no additional context.